# How to import multiple files in matlab, using uigetfile and importdata?

Tags: matlab, loops, user-interface, import

I want to select multiple files, import the data from the files and use them in GUI program.
The code I am using to get the multiple files works perectly well:

```
[FileName,PathName,FilterIndex] = uigetfile('*.txt*','Study Files','MultiSelect','on')

Cols = size(FileName,2);
numfiles = Cols;


for i = 1:numfiles
    FileName(i)

    entirefile =fullfile(PathName,FileName(i))
end
```

My problem is when I try to open `entire file`. The method I'm trying to use works with a single file but not here.When the code in the loop is:

```
for i = 1:numfiles
    FileName(i)

    entirefile =fullfile(PathName,FileName(i))

 A = [];
 fid = fopen(entirefile);

 tline = fgets(fid);
 while ischar(tline)
     parts = textscan(tline, '%f;');
     if numel(parts{1}) > 0
         A = [ A ; parts{:}' ];
      end
     tline = fgets(fid);

 end  
end
```

> Error using fopen   First input must be a file name of type char, or a
>   file identifier of type double.
>
> Error in multiselect (line 14)    fid = fopen(entirefile);

It also only gives me the first and last file selected and then only the `entirefile` of the first selected file.

Anyone any suggestions on how I could resolve this issue?

Comment: is this intended: `fid = fopen(file)`? or should it be `fopen(entirefile)`?

Comment: Sorry it should be fopen(entirefile) edited just in the question to avoid confusion. @Jigg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is how you access the element of the cell array `FileName`. If you access it with regular brackets, the output will be a one-element cell array, and `fullfile` will therefore output a cell array as well. You need to access it with curly brackets like this `FileName{i}`.

This should work:

```
[FileName,PathName,FilterIndex] = uigetfile('*.txt*','MultiSelect','on');

numfiles = size(FileName,2);

for ii = 1:numfiles
    FileName{ii}

    entirefile =fullfile(PathName,FileName{ii})

    fid = fopen(entirefile);
    % your code

    fclose(fid);

end
```

Comment: Could you try help me further? I would like to save `entire file` into a matrix of array so I can then process each of the files. I have tried using `entirefile = [];
for i = 1:numfiles
    entirefile =fullfile(PathName,FileName{i});
end  ` but when I try to view whats in entirefile I get 0 or just entirefile = [] . Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user3580436 best practice on this site is usually to ask one question at a time. But briefly, make a cell array out of `entirefile` like this: `entirefile{ii}=fullfile(PathName,FileName{ii})` and access it again with: `fid = fopen(entirefile{ii})`

Comment: Thank you, but when I tried this it did not work, it produced the error: Undefined function or variable 'ii'.

Error in multiselect (line 8)
    entirefile{ii} =fullfile(PathName,FileName{ii});

Comment: @user3580436 … you used `i` instead of `ii` in your code…