# How to save data ceated in for loop to an array? Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, global

I am using a for loop to save the path and names of multiple files I wish to process using a GUI in matlab. My code is as follows:

```
% --- Executes on button press in MultiSelect.
function MultiSelect_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to MultiSelect (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
[FileName,PathName,FilterIndex] = uigetfile('*.txt*','Study Files','MultiSelect','on');

Cols = size(FileName,2);
numfiles = Cols;


for i = 1:numfiles
    file{i} =fullfile(PathName,FileName{i});
end
 handles.gettinginfo = file ;
 guidata(hObject,handles)

    Fid = fopen(file{i});
 data1 = handles.gettinginfo(2);

%  for ii = 1:numfiles
   B = [];

      fid = fopen(data1);

  tline = fgets(fid);
 while ischar(tline)
     parts = textscan(tline, '%f;');
     if numel(parts{1}) > 0
B = [ B ; parts{:}' ];
     end
     tline = fgets(fid);

 end
```

I'm having an issue when I try to use `data1` with `fopen`, it gives me the error:
Error using fopen
First input must be a file name of type char, or a file identifier of type double.

But `data1 = handles.gettinginfo(2);` gives me the path and name of the file of the second selected file so I don't really understand why it fopen does not work.

I would like to save the selected files that is created in the for loop to a global array. What is the best way to do this? When I try to use `file{i}` to import the data from the file etc, it overwrites the other files and only produces info on the last file but I think the global array may help with this issue.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23759915/2777181

Comment: If you want to understand why a line does not work: Run the code with `dbstop if error` and inspect everything on the line. If you still don't understand it please just post the relevant code and variables here and adjust your question.